# A question regarding parametrization of a curve

Tags: surfaces, curves

So I have a curve(in $\mathbb{R}^3$) descripted as an intersection of two surfaces:
$$z^2=x^2+y^2, z=1-y$$

so I get

$$x=\sqrt{1-2y}$$
$$y=y$$
$$z=1-y$$

Is this a good parametrization.
But what does this Curve represent? How can I draw it from this? And how can I bound y? is it just $y\in{\mathbb{R}}$ or should I bound it differently.

Any help would be apreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not quite right. You have $$x^2=1-2y.$$ That doesn't imply that $$x=\sqrt{1-2y}$$ but rather $$x=\pm \sqrt{1-2y}.$$ From the former you can get a bound on $y:$ $$1-2y=x^2\geq 0$$ i.e. $$y\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @asdf so the parametrization is as : $r(y)=(|\sqrt{1-2y}|,y,1-y), y\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, right?

Comment: what curve? x^2+y^2=z^2 is a cone z=1-y a plain. so the curve is ?

Comment: Still, $x$ and $y$ can be negative. The $2$ answers below provide more insight.

Answer (score 1):

The first surface is a cone.  The second surface is a plane parallel to the angle of the cone, so the curve is a parabola lying in the plane $z=1-y.$

You have

$$(1-y)^2 = x^2+y^2$$

So

$$y=\frac{1-x^2}{2}$$

is the equation of the projection of the parabola  onto the $xy$-plane.

So let $x$ be your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No, since you have lost those points of the curve whose first coordinate is negative. Note that, since $x^2=1-2y$, you have $y=\frac{1-x^2}2$ and $z=1-y=\frac{1+x^2}2$. So, take the parametrization$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x=t\\y=\frac{1-t^2}2\\z=\frac{1+t^2}2,\end{array}\right.$$with $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is $t\in\mathbb{R}$ or is it bounded somehow?

Comment: I have added to my answer that $t\in\mathbb R$.